# How do I view the archives?

Tags: xcom-2

At the beginning of the game, one of the characters told me to view the archives to learn the history of the war.  I figured I could do that after I visited the lab, so I went there first.

However, after visiting the labs the "archives" button is gone, and it hasn't returned after the first mission.

Does it ever come back?  Is there some other way to view the archives, or do I need to restart the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it comes back a short while later.  It's under Command --> XCOM Archives